# How to open gallery when touch input type file in react native webview

Tags: android, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I'm currently working on React Native and using [React Native Webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) in my project.

What I want is to provide `take a picture` and `gallery` to Android users who touches
 in Webview like down below.

[choose the task including gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1t1R.png)

But my App provides the task menus including `file` not `gallery`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xcBm.png)

Please need a help!

here's my version information

"react-native": "0.71.6",
"react-native-webview": "^12.0.1"

I tried to append `accept` attribute to input like 
but it doesn't work at all.